# iOS - iPhone app won't enlarge to fit iPad screen

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, fullscreen

When running my `iPhone Only` app on an iPad, The '2x' button on the bottom right of the screen doesn't work, and I can't enlarge my application to fit the whole screen *(or more of)* the screen.

- The iPhone app is compatible with iPhones sizes *(has launchscreen assets)* for the 4/5/6/6+/X
- The iPad i tested in is an iPad Air 2

==> I tried toggling `App requires fullscreen`, but didn't work.

==> I also tested with another target which *(besides the previously stated sizes)* was also compatible with the iPhones XR and XS Max screen sizes. But still couldn't enlarge the app (2x mode button just doesn't want to work).

I don't want to set my app as Universal, just make it zoom on iPad.
I've looked everywhere but didn't see anyone having the same problem. Can someone relate to this issue and/or help me find a solution please ?

Comment: If your app is not Universal then it runs in iPhone compatibility mode on iPads. That is why you are seeing the 2x button. There is no way around that. Why don't you want to make your app Universal?

Comment: For the 1x/2x option on the iPad to work, the iPhone-only app must be written to support 3.5" iPhones. Then it can appear small or large (where it fills most of the iPad screen).

Comment: @maddy5 I already had a launchscreen for iPhone 4 (3.5"), now I've added the one for iPhone 3GS too. But no success.
By "must be written to support", did you mean something else ? Like changing the minimum deployment target ? (In my case it's iOS 9.3).